# I'm trying to pass javascript variable by a url

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to pass the java-script variable value by a URL and the URL is for load i-frame here my code

```
var child_id = 4;

$(newelement).html('<iframe id="becky_bunnyQ1" style="width:92%;height:100%;display:block;position:absolute;border: none;padding-left: 4%;" scrolling="no" src="pages/page20/index.html?id="'+child_id+'></iframe>');
```

Comment: Please elaborate what is not working

Comment: move quotes from here `id="`, place it after inserted id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake when setting the `src` attribute. Should be:

```
$(newelement).html('<iframe id="becky_bunnyQ1" 
style="width:92%;height:100%;display:block;position:absolute;border: 
none;padding-left: 4%;" scrolling="no" 
src="pages/page20/index.html?id='+child_id+'"></iframe>');
```